# Getting the first and last 32 bits of a uint64

Tags: matlab

How to get the first 32 bits and last 32 bits of a uint64, and save them to two uint32 variables, using low-level operations such as bitshift, and, xor...? It seems like an easy problem but Matlab has some limitations on bit manipulation (e.g. only support up to 53 bit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is supplementary to @Oleg's correct answer, in response to @Ruofeng's comment.

By doing `hex2dec` you are converting to `double` which doesn't have enough precision to store your hex number `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa` exactly. If you stick to uint64 you are OK.

See http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26005-convert-a-number-in-hex-to-uint64/content/hex2uint64.m.

Then `x64=hex2uint64('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa');` followed by Oleg's answer [i.e. `x32 = typecast(x64,'uint32');`] gives the two parts identical:

```
x32 =

  2863311530  2863311530
```

Answer (score 3):

You can `typecast()` it into `'uint32'` and convert to binary:

```
x64 = uint64(43564);
x32 = typecast(x64,'uint32');
x32 =
       43564           0

dec2bin(x32)
ans =
1010101000101100
0000000000000000
```

Comment: if x64 = uint64(hex2dec('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa')), then the two parts of x32 aren't identical?

Comment: @Ruofeng Please see Ramashalanka's answer.